# Inserting rows into SQL Server using EF + WCF Data Services .Net 4 Framework

Tags: odata, wcf-data-services

I recently deployed a .Net 4 WCF Data Service hosted on IIS 6, within a corporate environment (intranet), using Entity Framework. I access the service using OData and have been successful retrieving data from tables hosted on SQL Server 2005.

The issue is that I am unable to insert new rows. What I've done so far is to set entity rights to ALL -> ie.

```
config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);
```

I'm using integrated security on IIS. When I do a `POST` using jQuery, it returns 500 error code. I'm able to insert rows to a local database in my development environment.

Thanks

Comment: Please try to enable detailed error messages on the server (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phaniraj/archive/2008/06/18/debugging-ado-net-data-services.aspx) and then update the question with the error message you get from the server.

Comment: Agreed - if you can provide additional information about the error that you're seeing, then we can provide some help.  Right now, I don't think you've provided enough information about the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I was receiving error

> "Unable to update the EntitySet because it has a DefiningQuery and no  >element exists in the  element to support the current >operation."

This was caused because the table, although having an identity field, didn't specify it as a Primary Key. Set the Primary key and all is well.

[Fixing the System.Data.UpdateException – DefiningQuery and no  Error](http://weblogs.asp.net/kencox/archive/2009/09/09/fixing-the-system-data-updateexception-definingquery-and-no-lt-insertfunction-gt-error.aspx) helped.

Thanks